# Local branches are tidy, but all the remote branches are still there... Any suggestions?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I have been happily merging branches locally via the "finish feature" option in "gitflow"... This also deletes the local version of that branch. I have only just realised all of my remotes copies of these branches are still up and running.

Should i merge the branches in on the remote rather than deleting them?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete a Git branch both locally and remotely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing the master on the remote should be enough to have those branches 'merged'.

You can then delete the remote copies with `git push <remote> :<branch>`.

Comment: ahhh, let me try this now